# AWS IoT on Win 10 IoT

Tags: windows-iot

I'm playing around with Win 10 IoT Core on my RPi 3 trying to connect to AWS IoT. To connect to AWS IoT as a device, you're supposed to use X.509 certificates but I can't find X.509 certificate support anywhere. I'm using M2Mqtt and I'm just not seeing anything for X.509 on a search in the Object Browser. Do I have to switch back to Raspbian if I want to do this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking into this as well, I also noticed there is no AWS SDK for C# for AWS IoT.

I think until there is .NET SDK, it is probably better to run on Raspbian.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow this instruction, Then you will get certificates,

1. You can create one yourself (using the right tools, such as keytool),
2. You can ask a Certification Authority to issue you one (either directly or using a tool such as keytool to generate the request).